# Getting URL path in mongodb

Tags: javascript, string, mongodb, url, nosql

I want to obtain the path of a URL, which is stored as a string in a mongodb collection.
For example:

```
For the url: "www.abc.com/hello.php?id=4#hello",
the path will be: "/hello.php"
```

Is there a way to do this in mongodb? I need the path to resolve URLs (having the same path) in a map operation.

Comment: I think that what you need is simply a regex, but no way to show you an implementation if you do not include the code or pseudocode you want to have in the end.

Comment: Umm. URI library in your chosen language. What on earth do the other tags here have to do with your question? Also answered many times before.

Comment: in javascript, i can do "var c = document.createElement("a"). But, DOM doesn't work in mongodb. What can the be alternative way?

Comment: @Neil If answered many times before, please post links instead of remarks. I have already googled, and havn't found anything useful.

Comment: You could use parseUri in your map function. [parseUri 1.2: Split URLs in JavaScript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri)

Comment: is your question (a) given a string returned from mongodb how do I get the path portion of the URL or (b) how do I return only the path portion of the string from MongoDB?  Or something else?

Comment: @Asya I already have a field (string) in a mongodb collection, which stores a URL. I want to get the path partion of that URL.

Comment: can you answer my question?  I can't tell what's preventing you from getting the path of the URL from the string. Do you not know the format the string will have?  Your question needs to be more specific, since we don't know what you already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Asya I know the format of the string. Its like the one given in the example (NOTE; the url will contain parameters, hash etc, which I need to exclude, i.e., I only need the path). I want to get the path in mongodb. As far as I have searched there is no direct implementation for this in mongodb. I tried javascipt's DOM method for doing this (document.createElement('a')). The part where I am stuck is: Are YOU aware of anything else (that I am not aware of) in mongodb/ javascript, that can help me here? Or should I write my own? Also, I don't want to use regexes.

Comment: You can do this (assuming "string" has that URL string in it): string.slice(string.indexOf("/"), string.indexOf("?")) but that only works if you know the sample string is exact format.   Btw, are you doing this processing in map function of mapReduce?